# type hint for an instance of any subclass of a class

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Is there a way to do the following?

```
def myfunction() -> any_subclass_of[MyClass]:
    ...
```

Because the following says there's incompatible types in assignment:

```
def myfunction() -> MyClass:
    ...

var: MySubClass = myfunction()
```

Type[MyClass] also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If `myfunction` can return *any* subclass of `MyClass`, then you don't know *which* it will return. So in `var: MySubClass`, you cannot be sure it's going to be `MySubClass`, it might also be `MyOtherSubClass`. Then there's no type-safety for `var`. If you're trying to use an attribute which only `MySubClass` defined, but you actually have an instance of `MyOtherSubClass`, you'll have an error. — You can only define one specific return type, and can only treat the return value as being that specific type.

Comment: Well, the point is that I know it will be a specific subclass because of values I'm passing to myfunction, which are generated dynamically through a long pipeline and validation, and thus too complex to type hint. What I'm asking is for a way to tell mypy that I'm expecting a subclass of Myclass, no matter what subclass.

Comment: That still won't give you type safety because of what I explained above. If you can predict the return value based on function input, consider [overloading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) the function signature. Otherwise you'll need to [forcefully override](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) the return type.

Comment: Are you asking about *values* of `MyClass` and `MySubClass`, or the types themselves?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that

```
def myfunction() -> any_subclass_of[MyClass]:
    ...
```

means that `myfunction` could return a value whose type is *any* possible subclass of `MyClass` (including `MyClass` itself), then the type hint is simply

```
def myfunction() -> MyClass:
    ...
```

Classes are covariant, so any instance of `MySubClass` is also an instance of `MyClass`.

The problem with

```
var: MySubClass = myfunction()
```

is that you are requiring that `myfunction` return a value that is not just an instance of `MyClass`, but *also* of `MySubClass`, and `myfunction` makes no such promise. For example,

```
def myfunction() -> MyClass:
    return MyClass()
```

or

```
class OtherClass(MyClass):
    pass


def myfunction() -> MyClass:
    return OtherClass()
```

A static type checker will not look inside a function hinted as returning `MyClass` to see which subclass it "actually" returns; the promise is that an instance of `MyClass` will be, no more and no less. As a result, you simply *cannot* assign the value of `myfunction()` to a variable annotated with `MySubClass`, because the type checker cannot guarantee that is safe.

---

`Type` is use to indicate that you will return an *actual* type, not a value of a type. For example,

```
def myfunction() -> Type[MyClass]
    return MySubClass


var : Type[MyClass] = myfunction()
```

is fine, because you asked that `var` be either `MyClass` or one of its subclasses, and that's what `myfunction` returns.

```
var : Type[MySubClass] = myfunction()
```

fails for the same reasons as above: no promise was made that the return value of `myfunction` would not only be `MyClass` or a subclass, but also `MySubClass` or a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You want [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar):</s> Doesn't work, see comments.

```py
from typing import TypeVar

MC = TypeVar("MC", bound="MyClass")

class MyClass:
    pass

class MySubClass(MyClass):
    pass

def myfunction() -> MC:
    ...

var: MySubClass = myfunction()
```

Comment: You don't actually need a `TypeVar`; `Type` is covariant, not invariant, so `def myfunction() -> Type[MyClass]` would suffice.

Comment: But this still fails because `myfunction` could return a value of some other subclass of `MyClass` which is *not* a subclass of `MySubClass`.

Comment: (I thought you were using `Type`, but I see that you are importing it without using it. It's not entirely clear if `myfunction` is meant to return an instance of a subtype, or a subtype itself.)

Comment: The `Type` import was a mistake, leftover from an earlier test. mypy does not find any issues with the above code.

Comment: I think this is a bug. Replace `...` with `return None`, and you get the obvious error that `None` is received when `MC` is expected. In fact, you get the same error even if you try to return an instance of `MySubClass` or even `MyClass`.

Comment: You're right, my mistake.